# How can i send some request from ios 5 app to server who is in local network, while app is in background?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

So, I have an iOS app which needs to communicate with a server all the time. Logical solution for this problem is using push notifications, but it's impossible because the app needs to be used only at local network (Server will be at the same network).

I have read about `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` but this should work for maximum 10 minutes, so it's not ok. Also I have read about some manipulations with audio/voip/location in background, but apps with this stuff can't be accepted at Apple App Store.

Is there some legal solution for this problem? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nope ... when your app is in the background, it's in the background :-)